# Height calculation ambiguity of fixed-positioned table container

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

Let's assume I have the following document structure:

```
    <div class='container-table'>
      <div class='container-cell'>
        <div class='content'>
         <!-- a lot of text, images, ... -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
  .container-table {
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:table;
  }

  .container-cell {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .content {
    position: relative;
    height:90%;
    width:90%;
    left:50%; 
    margin-left:-45%;
    overflow:scroll;
  }
```

The idea is to have vertically- and horizontally-centered box that takes up 90% of the viewport's height and width. If the `content` div overflows, it should simply scroll.

This solution works fine in Chrome and Safari but does not in Firefox. The inspector shows the problem: Firefox ignores the `position:fixed` when `display:table` is present and calculates the height of `container-table` by summing up the height of its children while Safari/Chrome calculate the height by looking at the browser's viewport (as it should according to `position:fixed`).

Here's a complete demo: https://jsfiddle.net/76pg43tx/

Who is right: Firefox or Safari/Chrome or both? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

One good solution you can use using css is following:

```
    .container-table {
        position:fixed;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        display:table;
      }

      .container-cell {
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }

      .content {
        position: fixed;
        height:90%;
        width:90%;
        left:50%; 
        margin-left:-45%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(0, -50%);
        overflow:scroll;
      }
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/76pg43tx/5/)

Comment: I know about this CSS3-based solution. Unfortunately this causes Safari's font rendering to go crazy in certain situations. I assume that's because of half pixels or something.

Comment: @RosarioRaulin For safari you have to use `-webkit-` Check: https://jsfiddle.net/76pg43tx/9/ .What is the issue of font there?

Comment: The font is blurry. Especially on non-retina displays this makes it nearly unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

this is other css :

```
* {
box-sizing:border-box;
 }
 .container-table {
    position:fixed;height:100%; width:100%; top:0; left:0;display:table;
}
.container-cell {
        position:relative;
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height:100%; top:0px; left:0px;
}
.content {
        position: absolute;
        height:90%; width:90%; top:5%; left:5%;
        overflow-y:scroll;
 }
```

[CLiCK HERE : J S FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/76pg43tx/8/)

Comment: This works for me even without changing the box-sizing. It also seems to work without setting `.container-cell`'s height to 100% (even though I'd think that you need it).

Answer (score 0):

One work around is to use javascript.

```
function resizeDiv() {
var vph = $(window).height();
var vpw = $(window).width();
}
```

once you have the height and width you can customise the div as you require.